# Resources for writing domain in normal form with respect to axes for double and triple integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, analytic-geometry

I am taking the calculus 2 exam, and I struggle writing the domains of general shapes in normal form so I can solve it by iteration, both for double integrals and for triple ones, can you explain or suggest me a resource specifically these with all the trips and tricks and notable examples? Thanks.

Comment: A boomerang effect: can you, yes you, give a basic reference for what you call "Set Builder Notation" which is not at all a current concept.

Comment: @JeanMarie I read it is called this way in English, however I'm referring to domain written in normal form in respect to an axis.

Comment: @JeanMarie - Say What?? Since when is [set builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) "not a current concept"? It is by far the common notation for defining sets. And I do not find any other common English terminology for it.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair Thanks... As English is not my native language, I thought that this "set builder notation" was more or less a computer science terminology. I had no idea that it is synonymous of "description by comprehension".

Comment: @JeanMarie - Okay. "Description by comprehension" is actually more general, since it (and the other terms mentioned in the article) refer to the general idea, rather than a specific notation. But set builder notation refers specifically to the $\{...\}$ notation (in either list or predicate form).

Comment: @Paul Sinclair : I see. Thank you very much for this clarification.